# Redux form with react and validators

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, redux-form

I m using redux form for the first time and I m having some troubles dealing with synchronous validators.

Actually, I m having the following component :

```
import React, {Component, PropTypes} from 'react';
import {Field} from 'redux-form';
/**
 * The SignupForm class definition
 */
export default class SignupForm extends Component {
    /**
     * The SignupForm props type
     */
    static propTypes = {
        handleSubmit: PropTypes.func,
    }

    /**
     * Render the SignupForm
     */
    render() {
        console.log(this.props); // nothing available concerning the error
        const {
            handleSubmit
        } = this.props;
        return (
            <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
                <Field name="email" component="input" required placeholder="Email" type="text"/>
                <Field name="emailConfirmation" component="input" required placeholder="Confirm your email" type="text"/>
                <Field name="password" component="input" required placeholder="Password" type="password"/>
                <Field name="passwordConfirmation" component="input" required placeholder="Confirm your password" type="password"/>
                <button type="submit" className="signup">Signup</button>
            </form>
        );
    }
}
```

And the following validator :

```
export default ({email, emailConfirmation}) => {
    const errors = {
        email: null
    };

    if (email !== emailConfirmation) {
        errors.email = 'The two email addresses are not the same';
    }
    console.log(errors); // the error is here
    return errors;
};
```

And map both the redux form and the validator using the reduxForm function :

```
import SignupForm from './../../components/signupForm/signupForm';
import validate from './signupForm.validators';
import {reduxForm} from 'redux-form';
export default reduxForm({
    form: 'signup',
    validate
})(SignupForm);
```

**My problem**

When I console.log inside of my validator the *errors object* on the return statement, I m well having my error telling that my email addresses are not the same.

But when I console.log *this.props* in my component, I can see an object with some redux-form properties and methods, but the error object is undefined.

I m probably making the things wrong, but I can't get how and why.

Any help ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When your validate function its called, you are creating an object "errors" and returning it, so redux-form will use that to inject to corresponding fields the errors.

in your case: your Field "email" should get in props: meta: {error: 'The two email addresses are not the same'}

Are you sure this is not happenning?

Did you check [official docs sample?](http://redux-form.com/6.3.1/examples/syncValidation/)

According to [Field docs](http://redux-form.com/6.3.1/docs/api/Field.md/) I understand you can only get to it at Field level

> meta.error : String [optional]
>
> The error for this field if its value is not passing validation. Both synchronous, asynchronous, and submit validation errors **will be reported here**.

Comment: Oh, it's only at a field level ? What if I need to make it happen at the form level ?

Comment: I think so, If you need to do that, you might want to save refs to those fields and create callable functions from parent. Or you can store it in redux and use selectors. Depends on your needs

Comment: You can create a form-level error at the `_error` key. i.e. `errors._error = 'Something wrong with whole form';`